# How to connect a python websocket to an AppSync subscription, with IAM Auth?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-iam, aws-appsync

I want python to open an AWS AppSync Subscription and receive the updates.

The official blog is hand-wavy over how to authenticate a websocket with IAM.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-websockets-python/

It defers to [this document about signing http requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html), which does not mention websockets, and thus provides no clues what to include, or exlude, or vary, to start a websocket.  I fear it is going to take me quite some time to digest, adapt, and test before I get anything happening.

```
IAM_header = {
    "accept": "application/json, text/javascript",
    "content-encoding": "amz-1.0",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "host": <HOST>,
    "x-amz-date": <ISO_UTC_TIMESTAMP>,,
    "X-Amz-Security-Token": <IAM SECURITY TOKEN>,
    "Authorization": <IAM SIGNATURE>
}
```

I don't suppose anyone has does this before and can share some insights, or code?

**IAM_SIGNATURE**
In the context of creating a websocket what are the "request_parameters" that we are signing?

So far I have fed details into requests_aws4auth and stuffed the headers from that into the websocket.  That effort received this sort of reply:

#### message

<< {"payload":{"errors":[{"errorType":"BadRequestException","message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\n**The Canonical String for this request should have been**\n'POST\n/graphql/connect\n\nhost:iutysrbt2qxx7ekx2xi.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934852b855\nx-amz-date:20200730T044539Z\nx-amz-security-token:FwoGZpgV9hfLzGbDiPLCK1HMsXYJapqB299GReKYAALLKPOgifkFMi2VZsiycpLbxp7ZDGGO4NfSgEaULYm9GMMkGIj1Ck/0YcckBNawWpisa6NxdMs=\n\nhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token\n44136fa355b3678a1b4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a'\n\n**The String-to-Sign should have been**\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20200730T044539Z\n20200730/ap-southeast-2/appsync/aws4_request\n29a5ecebf83602958c569f1ae18b5fa8353dd04833a833885'\n"}]},"type":"connection_error"}

So I need to work out the "Canonical String", the "String-to-Sign", and how to stuff them into the Authorization header.

Answer (score 0):

[graphql-python/gql](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) supports AWS AppSync since [version 3.0.0rc0](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql/releases/tag/v3.0.0rc0).

It supports queries, mutation and even subscriptions on the realtime endpoint.

It supports IAM, api key and JWT authentication methods.

The documentation is available [here](https://gql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transports/appsync.html)

Here is an example of a subscription using the IAM authentication:

```py
import asyncio
import os
import sys

from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.appsync_websockets import AppSyncWebsocketsTransport

# Uncomment the following lines to enable debug output
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():

    # Should look like:
    # https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appsync-api.REGION.amazonaws.com/graphql
    url = os.environ.get("AWS_GRAPHQL_API_ENDPOINT")

    if url is None:
        print("Missing environment variables")
        sys.exit()

    transport = AppSyncWebsocketsTransport(url=url)

    async with Client(transport=transport) as session:

        subscription = gql(
            """
subscription onCreateMessage {
  onCreateMessage {
    message
  }
}
"""
        )

        print("Waiting for messages...")

        async for result in session.subscribe(subscription):
            print(result)


asyncio.run(main())
```